# Can't catch exception in try-catch C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, try-catch

This exception is being thrown, and I apparently have no way to catch it:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000

Source:

```
Line 102:            try
Line 103:            {
Line 104:                var blobClient = GetClient();  <-- throws here
Line 105:                var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
Line 106:                container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
```

> Source File: ...Blob.cs    Line: 104

The entire function:

```
private static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(string containerName)
{
    try
    {
        var blobClient = GetClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
        return container;
    }
    catch (HttpException ex)
    {
        Helpers.Error.Functions.RecordError(ex);
        throw new HttpException(500, "Could not connect.");
    }
}
```

The `GetClient()` function:

```
private static CloudBlobClient GetClient()
{
    try
    {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Deployment.AzureConnectionString);
        return account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.Error.Functions.RecordError(ex);
        throw new HttpException(500, "Could not connect GetClient.");
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

> [SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) +520
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) +621
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1724
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:699
>
> [StorageException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:604
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType
>   accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext
>   operationContext) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:233
>   C3.Code.Controls.Application.Storage.Blob.Blob.GetContainer(String
>   containerName) in ...Blob.cs:104
>   C3.Code.Controls.Application.Storage.Blob.Blob.AddBlob(String
>   containerName, String blobReference, Byte[] bytes) in D:\Dropbox
>   (Scirra Ltd)\Tom\C3
>   Website\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Storage\Blob\Blob.cs:87
>   C3.Code.Callbacks.Application.ApplicationStart() in D:\Dropbox (Scirra
>   Ltd)\Tom\C3 Website\C3Alpha2\Code\Callbacks\Application.cs:26
>   C3.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Dropbox
>   (Scirra Ltd)\Tom\C3 Website\C3Alpha2\Global.asax.cs:30
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +534
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +175
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +424
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +360
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +118    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +730

Comment: this is probably the behavior while you debugging in VS, there is settings of exceptions in VS, you need to tweak that

Comment: I'm a bit confused you deleted the old question instead of editing it.

Comment: You're only trying to catch a `HttpException`, everything else will not get caught. You exception is actually a `SocketException` I think.

Comment: have you tried catching a WebException?

Comment: Sorry @Mighty, thought I'd solved it so didn't want to waste anyone's time.  Turned out I didn't solve it.

Comment: @DavidG doh that's it!  Thanks for the spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception message you posted:

> [**SocketException** (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000]

Note that this is a `SocketException`, not an `HttpException` but your code says this:

```
catch (HttpException ex)
```

So it's not being caught. Either use a generic `Exception` to catch everything, or switch to catching `SocketException`.

Comment: But he catches all exceptions and then wraps them into `HttpException` in GetClient.

Comment: @Evk Then we may be looking at different code, the stack trace clearly says the exception is a `SocketException`.

Comment: Yes but author claims that GetClient throws, and it can only throw HttpException, because OP catches all exceptions there and then manually throws HttpException. Anyway it seems that after all it is not GetClient which throws.

Comment: @Evk I know, but claims vs reality are often very different. The only absolutely reliable information we have is the stack trace (because it's very time consuming to simplify/fake that)